# Regulary get django.db.utils.InterfaceError in my bot

Tags: postgresql, exception, database-connection, django-orm, aiogram

I use aiogram with Django ORM for my bot.
Often, I encounter the following error: "django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected" and as a result, the ORM loses the database connection and I get an InterfaceError.

I have already added the CONN_MAX_RETRIES and CONN_RETRY_DELAY settings, but the ORM still loses the connection.
The problem can be solved by restarting the Docker container.
Is there a way to solve this issue through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use try except

```py
# For django ORM fix next exceptions
# django.db.utils.InterfaceError
# django.db.utils.OperationalError

from django.db import close_old_connections
close_old_connections()
```

```py
# For sqlalchemy with aldjemy fix next exceptions
# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError

from aldjemy.orm import get_session
from django.db import close_old_connections

close_old_connections()
get_session(recreate=True)
```